# VirtualHost: поддомены ссылаются на главный домен

Tags: веб-сервер, php, hosts, hosting, virtual

Добрый день. Такая проблемка: при открытии поддомена, открывает файлы главного домена. Помогите пожалуйста, 3 дня уже мучаюсь :(

***Вот конфиг***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName dungeon-defenders.ru    ServerAlias www.dungeon-defenders.ru *.dungeon-defenders.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/site    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error/dungeon-defenders.ru.log    CustomLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/access/dungeon-defenders.ru.log combined<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/site>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/site>    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName forum.dungeon-defenders.ru    ServerAlias www.forum.dungeon-defenders.ru *.forum.dungeon-defenders.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/forum    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error/forum.dungeon-defenders.ru.log    CustomLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/access/forum.dungeon-defenders.ru.log combined<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/forum>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory "/hdd/backup/www/forum">    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName wiki.dungeon-defenders.ru    ServerAlias www.wiki.dungeon-defenders.ru *.wiki.dungeon-defenders.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error/wiki.dungeon-defenders.ru.log    CustomLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/access/wiki.dungeon-defenders.ru.log combined<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki>    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Зачем у вас два раза прописаны опции для /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот скриншот --> http://take.ms/hMAzH

- я сейчас поставил nginx. Ничего плохого не произошло. Но поддомены тоже не заработали

Comment: Проблема решена. Была допущена ошибка в конфиге. Стояла звёздочка перед главным доменом. А нико не заметил..

Answer (score 0):

В конфиг Apache пропишите это - NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: httpd -t введите это в терминале и скопируйте сюда, что выдаст.

Comment: [root@GameServers ~]# httpd -tSyntax OK

Comment: Тогда возвращаемся к тому, что я написал к предыдущему вопросу. Скопируйте настройки DNS в панели, где вы купили домен. Выложите сюда, ИП адрес можете изменить.

Comment: В вашей панели можно прописывать запись CNAME? Я не разглядел :)Найдите эту настройку и сделайте так:forum CNAME dungeon-defenders.ru.Проверьте, если заработает, то по аналогии сделаете для остальных поддоменов. И смените TTL на 600. Так быстрее будет происходить обновление ваших данных.

Comment: http://take.ms/L4rdJ - ошибка добавления...

Comment: dungeon-defenders.ru. ТОЧКУ в конце забыли.

Comment: Не получается всё ровно. Я никогда CNAME не делал. Поддомены и без него работали. Что же сейчас изменилось? Небось что-то в конфиге. Точно он правильный?